# information regarding transit visa for Jordan

Tags: transit, schengen-visas, pakistani-citizens, jordan

[image]

My air ticket picture is attached.

I have purchased this Air ticket and its route is Warsaw-Amman then Amman-Dubai and Dubai-Pakistan.

In each transit i have stay for 2 hours and 30 minutes maximum, but on my ticket it is showing that i need visa in Jordan.

someone told me that i will get my baggage at Amman airport therefore i need visa to immigrate and rebook for the next flight.

Can you help me out with this issue, do i really need visa or not.

Comment: What is your nationality? And what, if any, visa(s) do you currently have?

Comment: my nationality is Pakistani. and i have polish temporarey residance card( Karta podyto). 3 years

Answer (score 2):

Your first flight segment is on a Ryanair flight. Ryanair does not have baggage interlining agreements with other airlines, as they are a low cost carrier. Thus you need to go through immigration, pick up your luggage, check it in for your next flight, and then go back through immigration for your next flight segment. This means two things: First, you need a (transit) visa, and second, you probably don't have enough time to make the connection. You probably should not purchase this itinerary.

Comment: and what if i do not carry any luggage with me but only laptop. still i will have to go through the immigration  ??

Comment: If you can check in for the second flight online, or at the first airport, then you should be able to do that. But are not guaranteed to be able to check in for the next flight in the international area of the airport in Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

[Timatic](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) suggests that you will not require a visa if you have a confirmed ticket onwards departing within 48 hours:

> National Pakistan (PK)/Residence Poland (PL)
> Transit Jordan (JO)
> Transit United Arab Emirates (AE)
> Destination Pakistan (PK)
>
> Jordan (JO)
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
> ticket for a flight to a third country within 48 hours. They
> must stay in the international transit area of the airport and
> have documents required for the next destination.

Comment: He will have to leave the international passenger area for his luggage